# javascript: NaN when getting average

Tags: javascript, html

So I followed this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4h6w64d8/2/
but unfortunately when I tried the code the average is NaN. 
In the fiddle even though a column has no value it will still calculate and display the average. However when I tried it, it will only display NaN.

This is my html:

```
<table id="scorecard_student" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Code </th>
        <th>PO 1</th>
        <th>PO 2</th>
        <th>PO 3</th>
        <th>PO 4</th>
        <th>PO 5</th>
        <th>PO 6</th>
        <th>PO 7</th>
        <th>PO 8</th>
        <th>PO 9</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td width="7%">ICT117</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>1.5</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="7%">ICT118</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td>1.5</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="7%">ICT110</td>
        <td>3.0</td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td width="7%">ICT111</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td>2.0</td>
        <td>1.5</td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>

    </tr>
</tbody>
<tfoot>
    <tr bgcolor="#FFF380">
        <td>
            <center>Average</center>
        </td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</tfoot>
</table>
```

My js:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var table = document.getElementById('scorecard_student'),
        rows = table.getElementsByTagName('tbody')[0].getElementsByTagName('tr'),
        footer = table.getElementsByTagName('tfoot')[0];


    for (var i = 1; i <= <? php echo $po_count; ?> ; i++) {
        var sum = numOfValues = 0;
        for (var j = 0, l = rows.length; j < l; j++) {
            try {
                sum += parseFloat(
                    rows[j].getElementsByTagName('td')[i]
                    .innerHTML
                );
                numOfValues++;
            } catch (e) {}
        }

        var avg = sum / numOfValues;
        footer.getElementsByTagName('td')[i]
            .innerHTML = Math.round(avg * 100) / 100;
    }
</script>
```

Update, I think I got it now.

```
if (rows[j].getElementsByTagName('td')[i].innerHTML != '') {
    sum += parseFloat(
        rows[j].getElementsByTagName('td')[i]
        .innerHTML
    ) || 0;

    numOfValues++;
}
```

Comment: IN fiddle in which td there is no value, then there is no <center> tag too.

Answer (score 3):

In some cases you get blank text, you need to skip it:

```
 sum += parseFloat(
            rows[j].getElementsByTagName('td')[i]
            .innerHTML
          ) || 0; //<--
```

Comment: thanks for the reply. it did work however it will divide by number of rows with value zero.

Comment: if(rows[j].getElementsByTagName('td')[i]                               
                    .innerHTML){
                        numOfValues++;
                }

add this to discard the effect on average of no value